# What does O(nm/8 * log(nm/8)) + O(nm/9 * log(nm/9)) + ... + O(nm/m * log(nm/m)) equal to?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm sorry for the question title but I can't find a simpler way to put it. Basically, my algorithm involves quicksort for O(nm/k) elements, where k ranges from 8 to m. I wonder what the total complexity for this is, and how to deduce it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Drop the division inside the logarithms and we get `nmlog(mn) * (1/8 + ... + 1/m) = O(nmlog(mn)log(m)) = O(mnlog(m)^2 + mnlog(m)log(n))`.   [I used the fact that the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) is asymptotically `ln(m)`)

Note that the fact that we dropped the divisions inside the logarithms means that we got an upper bound rather than an exact bound (but a better one than the naive approach of taking the biggest term multiplied by `m`).